# Passing an array of objects to the $project stage of a mongo aggregate

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, javascript-objects

I'm currently trying to fix a bug in a piece of software. I have a for loop where I'm iterating through some data and then, for each piece of data I'm creating a new property in an object with a specific value. Kind of something like this:

```
let myObject = {};
for(iterate through data) {
    myObject[data.name] = data.content;
}
```

The problem is that, sometimes, `data.name` can have the same value, meaning that at a certain point some data might be overridden with a consequent loss of information.

I have tried to solve this problem by using an array of objects, but I simply cannot pass such a structure to the `$project` part of an aggregation.

I have a necessity to be able to pass the above-mentioned object the `$project` stage of a mongo aggregate. How can I solve this problem? Is there any way I can solve it by either changing my data structure or by using some tools in the project?

Comment: How do you expect the mongodb query to match the document? You have an array of values in a field. Should the document contains one or all of the values to be matched?

Comment: Could you please show your data, query you're trying to build and expected output ?